# Count number of keys inside an object in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to find out how many seats have been ordered in a show.

Each show document has a 'showTakenSeats' object in it.

Here is the initial data:

```
    [
    {
        "_id": "5b658d37692f2e3c881960cb",
        "_MovieId": "5b5835dd86ab401494263861",
        "_TheaterId": "5b3dfeb217bc8c23f0e7ec3f",
        "dateTime": "2018-08-04T14:00:00.000Z",
        "showTakenSeats": {
            "0-0": "5b658f79dd8bb938289e2e0b",
            "0-1": "5b658f79dd8bb938289e2e0b",
            "0-2": "5b658f79dd8bb938289e2e0b"
        },
        "__v": 0,
    },
    {
        "_id": "5b658d4a692f2e3c881960cc",
        "_MovieId": "5b584eb186ab401494263868",
        "_TheaterId": "5b45d269a53b0c05f8959260",
        "dateTime": "2018-08-04T13:00:00.000Z",
        "showTakenSeats": {
            "0-0": "5b65904bdd8bb938289e2e0d",
            "0-1": "5b65904bdd8bb938289e2e0d",
            "0-2": "5b65904bdd8bb938289e2e0d"
        },
        "__v": 0,
    },
    {
        "_id": "5b658fd1dd8bb938289e2e0c",
        "_MovieId": "5b575452478afb72ec65f8f6",
        "_TheaterId": "5b45d219a53b0c05f895925f",
        "dateTime": "2018-08-04T20:00:00.000Z",
        "showTakenSeats": {},
        "__v": 0,
    },
    {
        "_id": "5b6593d80d48d9394877dd09",
        "_MovieId": "5b584eb186ab401494263868",
        "_TheaterId": "5b446a8768db4e2e980723ab",
        "dateTime": "2018-08-05T10:00:00.000Z",
        "showTakenSeats": {},
        "__v": 0,
    },
    {
        "_id": "5b65943b0d48d9394877dd0a",
        "_MovieId": "5b584eb186ab401494263868",
        "_TheaterId": "5b446a8768db4e2e980723ab",
        "dateTime": "2018-08-03T22:00:00.000Z",
        "showTakenSeats": {},
        "__v": 0,
    }
]
```

Here is my code:

```
Show.aggregate([
        {
            $addFields: {'count':Object.keys('$showTakenSeats').length}
        }

    ], function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            //next(err);
            return res.json(err);
        } else {
            res.json(result);
        }
    });
```

And here are the results:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5b658d37692f2e3c881960cb",
        "_MovieId": "5b5835dd86ab401494263861",
        "_TheaterId": "5b3dfeb217bc8c23f0e7ec3f",
        "dateTime": "2018-08-04T14:00:00.000Z",
        "showTakenSeats": {
            "0-0": "5b658f79dd8bb938289e2e0b",
            "0-1": "5b658f79dd8bb938289e2e0b",
            "0-2": "5b658f79dd8bb938289e2e0b"
        },
        "__v": 0,
        "count": 15
    },
    {
        "_id": "5b658d4a692f2e3c881960cc",
        "_MovieId": "5b584eb186ab401494263868",
        "_TheaterId": "5b45d269a53b0c05f8959260",
        "dateTime": "2018-08-04T13:00:00.000Z",
        "showTakenSeats": {
            "0-0": "5b65904bdd8bb938289e2e0d",
            "0-1": "5b65904bdd8bb938289e2e0d",
            "0-2": "5b65904bdd8bb938289e2e0d"
        },
        "__v": 0,
        "count": 15
    },
    {
        "_id": "5b658fd1dd8bb938289e2e0c",
        "_MovieId": "5b575452478afb72ec65f8f6",
        "_TheaterId": "5b45d219a53b0c05f895925f",
        "dateTime": "2018-08-04T20:00:00.000Z",
        "showTakenSeats": {},
        "__v": 0,
        "count": 15
    },
    {
        "_id": "5b6593d80d48d9394877dd09",
        "_MovieId": "5b584eb186ab401494263868",
        "_TheaterId": "5b446a8768db4e2e980723ab",
        "dateTime": "2018-08-05T10:00:00.000Z",
        "showTakenSeats": {},
        "__v": 0,
        "count": 15
    },
    {
        "_id": "5b65943b0d48d9394877dd0a",
        "_MovieId": "5b584eb186ab401494263868",
        "_TheaterId": "5b446a8768db4e2e980723ab",
        "dateTime": "2018-08-03T22:00:00.000Z",
        "showTakenSeats": {},
        "__v": 0,
        "count": 15
    }
]
```

The results of count are incorent. it seems that '`Object.keys('$showTakenSeats').length`' return 15 all the time. instead of the real value which should be different.

The results of count should be (3,3,0,0,0)

Anybody knows whats the problem? 
Thanks!

Comment: You're getting the length of the string "$showTakenSeats".

Comment: @Pointy you are right! any idea how can i get the desired value?

Comment: Well I'm afraid I am not familiar with the framework you're using.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can convert first object to array with [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) and then can find the [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) of the array

```
Show.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "count": {
      "$size": {
        "$objectToArray": "$showTakenSeats"
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thanks. i just figured it out myself .. :)

Comment: great and glad to help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the aggregation framework but a simple javascript solution should be like that

```js
var  data =   [
    {
        "_id": "5b658d37692f2e3c881960cb",
        "_MovieId": "5b5835dd86ab401494263861",
        "_TheaterId": "5b3dfeb217bc8c23f0e7ec3f",
        "dateTime": "2018-08-04T14:00:00.000Z",
        "showTakenSeats": {
            "0-0": "5b658f79dd8bb938289e2e0b",
            "0-1": "5b658f79dd8bb938289e2e0b",
            "0-2": "5b658f79dd8bb938289e2e0b"
        },
        "__v": 0,
    },
    {
        "_id": "5b658d4a692f2e3c881960cc",
        "_MovieId": "5b584eb186ab401494263868",
        "_TheaterId": "5b45d269a53b0c05f8959260",
        "dateTime": "2018-08-04T13:00:00.000Z",
        "showTakenSeats": {
            "0-0": "5b65904bdd8bb938289e2e0d",
            "0-1": "5b65904bdd8bb938289e2e0d",
            "0-2": "5b65904bdd8bb938289e2e0d"
        },
        "__v": 0,
    },
    {
        "_id": "5b658fd1dd8bb938289e2e0c",
        "_MovieId": "5b575452478afb72ec65f8f6",
        "_TheaterId": "5b45d219a53b0c05f895925f",
        "dateTime": "2018-08-04T20:00:00.000Z",
        "showTakenSeats": {},
        "__v": 0,
    },
    {
        "_id": "5b6593d80d48d9394877dd09",
        "_MovieId": "5b584eb186ab401494263868",
        "_TheaterId": "5b446a8768db4e2e980723ab",
        "dateTime": "2018-08-05T10:00:00.000Z",
        "showTakenSeats": {},
        "__v": 0,
    },
    {
        "_id": "5b65943b0d48d9394877dd0a",
        "_MovieId": "5b584eb186ab401494263868",
        "_TheaterId": "5b446a8768db4e2e980723ab",
        "dateTime": "2018-08-03T22:00:00.000Z",
        "showTakenSeats": {},
        "__v": 0,
    }
]


var withCount = data.map(function(e){
  return Object.assign({count: Object.keys(e.showTakenSeats).length}, e);
})

console.log(withCount);
```

Comment: thanks. but it's not really working for me